# Deformations of a compact complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a compact, complex manifold and $A\in \textbf{Art}$ where $\textbf{Art}$ is the category of local artinian $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with residue field $\mathbb{C}$.

In page 24 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701091v1.pdf) they define an infinitesimal deformation of $X$ over $Spec(A)$ to be the following diagram:

$$
\matrix{
  X                    & \overset{i}{\rightarrow}   & X_A                    \cr
  \downarrow &                      & \downarrow \pi \cr
  Spec(\mathbb{C})                  & \overset{i}{\rightarrow} & Spec(A)                  \cr
}
$$

where $\pi$ is proper and flat holomorphic map, $a\in Spec(A)$ is the closed point, $i$ is a closed embedding, and $X\simeq X_A\times_{Spec_(A)} Spec(\mathbb{C})$.

This definition looks a lot like a deformation of a scheme. But $X,X_A$ are not necessarily schemes (or are they?). My question is, does this definition make sense? And what is a flat morphism of manifolds?

Also, in ch. 4 of his [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540226147), Kodaira defines a deformation of a complex manifold $X$ to be a deformation of the transitions functions that glue together the polydisks that cover $X$. Are these definitions the same?